# How to make separately unique each column in postgresql?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, primary-key, composite-primary-key

I know we can apply primary key to a column to provide uniqueness for a row and we can apply multiple primary keys and get a composite key.

But this didn't work for my case. I have userID and email columns. And I want them to be unique at the same time. When I applied primary key attribute to both of them a person with same email but different userID can be added to the table. So composite key is like a combination I suppose, when userID changes there is no need to change email.

I am using psycopg2 module with python and I can do this uniqueness while user registration by searching rows if there is a same email and ask the user for change in email for uniqueness. But I want to learn is there way to do this kind of separate uniqueness with postgresql/sql.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to make it an id! Just make it a unique constraint.
For example like this:

```
CREATE TABLE orders(
id integer PRIMARY KEY,
email VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the *Unique* constraint. You can use it as below:

```
CREATE TABLE person (
   id serial PRIMARY KEY,
   first_name VARCHAR (50),
   last_name VARCHAR (50),
   email VARCHAR (50) UNIQUE
);
```

In case of primary key you cant keep null values but with unique you can have null as long as it is not duplicated across rows. Primary key is a combination of *NOT NULL* and *Unique* constraint.